# Why does invoking callable properties in PHP 7 work?

Tags: php, php-7

Consider the following code:

```
interface Doll
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function __invoke();
}

class LargeDoll
{
    private $inner;

    function __construct(Doll $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->inner() . ' world';
    }
}
```

This won't work because it is expecting `$this->inner` to be a method, rather than a callable property.

Then it occurred to me, just like having `(new LargeDoll)();` would work, what about if the property was wrapped in paranthesis also? So I tested it on 3v4l:

```
return ($this->inner)() . ' world';
```

[And found that it works for PHP 7, but not for previous versions.](https://3v4l.org/NsfQ0)

However, I can't find any mention of this [in the changelogs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

Where can I find more information about this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability to use IIFE's (which `($this->inner)()` effectively is) was added as part of the [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) by Nikita Popov, which was implemented in PHP7.

It's a consequence of better variable syntax handling in the parser. Considering one of the goals of PHP7 was to overhaul syntax parsing, I think they've achieved some real progress there.